# Internal exception in StandardCompiler when trying the Solidity 0.8.21 version

Tags: solidity

Did you know what is the meaning of "qualified access to events from other contracts" from [Solidity 0.8.21 Release Announcement](https://soliditylang.org/blog/2023/07/19/solidity-0.8.21-release-announcement)?

I was trying this, but does not work:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.21;

contract A {
    event EventInA();

    function call() public {
        emit EventInA();
    }
}

contract B {
    // event EventInB();

    function call() public {
        emit A.EventInA();
    }
```

That is the full code. The error throws in the first line with this message:

```
Internal exception in StandardCompiler::compile: /solidity/libsolidity/interface/Natspec.cpp(89): Throw in function static Json::Value solidity::frontend::Natspec::userDocumentation(const ContractDefinition &)
Dynamic exception type: boost::wrapexcept<solidity::langutil::InternalCompilerError>
std::exception::what: Solidity assertion failed
[solidity::util::tag_comment*] = Solidity assertion failed
```

I expected to access to the EventInA event in contract A from contract B

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known bug](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/14430) in v0.8.21 that already has a [fix](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/14434).

The fix is likely going to be released in v0.8.22 (not released yet as of July 23, 2023).